# Image won't display in JFrame

Tags: image, jframe

I am trying to get an image to display inside my JFrame and having no success. I have followed the [Oracle tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/drawimage.html) exactly and I get a NullPointerException:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at net.ultibyte.TheDo.CreateLoginScreen.DisplayImage(CreateLoginScreen.java:35)
at net.ultibyte.TheDo.CreateLoginScreen.main(CreateLoginScreen.java:41)
```

Below is my code.

```
public class CreateLoginScreen extends JFrame {

CreateLoginScreen() {
    setTitle("TheDo");
    setSize(1280, 720);
    setVisible(true);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}

public static Image loadImage() {
    Image i = null;
    try {
        i = ImageIO.read(new File("src/resources/LoginScreen.png"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }
    return i;
}

public static void DisplayImage(Image i) {
    Graphics g = i.getGraphics();
    g.drawImage(i, 0, 0, null);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    CreateLoginScreen a = new CreateLoginScreen();
    DisplayImage(loadImage());
}

}
```

And the image is named "LoginScreen.png", and is located in a package called "resources" which is in the src folder.

I have no idea what's wrong and would very much appreciate any help :).

**Update**: Corrected file path, pointed out by [peeskillet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2587435/peeskillet). This fixed the NullPointerException. Still won't display image though.

Answer (score 0):

> *"located in a package called "resources" which is in the src folder."*

You need to use this file path. `"src/resources/LoginScreen.png"`

Your IDE will first look in the main project folder. since src is direct child of the project root, you need to add that to the path

---

**EDIT**

> *"The window loads up but no image is displayed. Any idea on this? "*

Yes, you need to override a paint method in order to draw the image on to the component. I wouldn't use `JFrame` though. I would use a `JPanel` and override the `paintComponent` method.

Try this out

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.*;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;

class JPanelTemplate extends JPanel {
    private static final int SCREEN_WIDTH = 400;

    BufferedImage img;

    public JPanelTemplate() {
        try {
            img = ImageIO.read(new File("src/resources/LoginScreen.png"));
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, this);
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_WIDTH);

    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.add(new JPanelTemplate());
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGui();

            }
        });
    }
}
```